# How to check for audio plagiarism?

Tags: audio, rights

I have a scenario of a global organization that has workers across the world uploading digital audio content and we need to confirm that their contributions are not reworked from older contributions but are original. For the volume and language barrier it is very hard to do manually.

Is there a program that can compare sound files to see if they contain the same or portions of the same audio?

If so can you provide details, tips, caveats?

Comment: Great question - very difficult to answer. Content ID is a technology used by youtube and other large media companies to achieve a similar goal, although it is proprietary technology and is also music-focussed. Will think further on this.

Comment: have you looked at https://acoustid.org/? this is as close as you are going to get without writing software yourself.